# SQL Server Spatial Index Nearest Neighbour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, spatial, spatial-index, spatial-query

I am trying to query geopoints for nearest neighbour, Whether I use spatial index or not, I always get similar times and it takes about 6 seconds. How can I speed this query up?

Here is my query:

```
Declare @param nvarchar(50);
set @param = 'POINT(32.489491 37.864724)'

Declare @paramGeom geometry = geometry::STPointFromText(@param, 4326);
Select top 1 MI_PRINX, MI_STYLE, TrafikIsigi, Demiryolu, UlkeSinir, ID, SP_GEOMETRY.STX AS Longitude, SP_GEOMETRY.STY AS Latitude, SP_GEOMETRY AS Geometry FROM dbo.NODE  (nolock)
WHERE NODE.SP_GEOMETRY.STDistance(@paramGeom) < 0.1
ORDER BY NODE.SP_GEOMETRY.STDistance(@paramGeom);
```

Here is my Index:

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [IX_Spatial] ON [dbo].[NODE] 
(
    [SP_GEOMETRY]
)USING  GEOMETRY_GRID 
WITH (
BOUNDING_BOX =(25, 35, 46, 43), GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = HIGH,LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_3 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_4 = MEDIUM), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 64, PAD_INDEX  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**

I changed my query like this:

```
Declare @param nvarchar(50);
set @param = 'POINT(32.489491 37.864724)'

Declare @paramGeom geometry = geometry::STPointFromText(@param, 4326);

Select top 1 MI_PRINX, MI_STYLE, TrafikIsigi, Demiryolu, UlkeSinir, ID, SP_GEOMETRY.STX AS Longitude, SP_GEOMETRY.STY AS Latitude, SP_GEOMETRY AS Geometry FROM [dbo].[NODE] n WITH (INDEX(IX_Spatial))
WHERE n.SP_GEOMETRY.STDistance(@paramGeom) < 0.1
ORDER BY n.SP_GEOMETRY.STDistance(@paramGeom);
```

Comment: I think this question is better suited for gis.stackexchange.com. And your question is confusing. Can't understand what you want.

Comment: I need to speed-up my query. This query takes about 6 seconds in 2M Node.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350965/how-can-i-speed-up-this-sql-server-spatial-query, it seems like it might be a similar problem and maybe its not using the spatial index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350965/how-can-i-speed-up-this-sql-server-spatial-query), it seems like it might be a similar problem and maybe its not using the spatial index. –