# How to use string variable for SQL Server index hint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, spatial

I have a SQL Server 2012 database table with geometry columns and there is a single Spatial index on this table.

I have a SQL query which I run to do some geospatial analysis (intersect/contains) and the performance of query execution differs a lot when forcing to use the spatial index and not (which according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350965/how-can-i-speed-up-this-sql-server-spatial-query) depends on the size of the table I use). My tables are just 1-2K of polys and 1-2K of points.

So, I use `WITH (INDEX(S7_idx))` in the SQL query where the `S7_idx` is the name of my Spatial index.

However, when I will execute this SQL query on another database that has the same table, the Spatial index might have another name. So, I don't want to hard-code the index name. I think it would be great if I could retrieve the index value dynamically as I can be sure that there is only one Spatial index on the table.

`select name from sys.indexes
where object_id = (select object_id from sys.objects where name = 'TableName')
AND type_desc = 'SPATIAL'`

The result:

`name
S7_idx`

Great. Now I want to use this value instead of hard-coded index name in the `WITH` statement. How do I do this?

I think I cannot use dynamic SQL (with `EXECUTE sp_executesql`) inside my `WITH (INDEX(...))` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `hints` are never recommended unless you have a well experienced DBA suggested it. Keeping the `statistics` up to data will solve so many issues.

If you are sure about the `hint` used, then you need to use dynamic query

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)= ''

SET @sql = 'SELECT *
FROM TableName
WITH (INDEX('
           + (SELECT NAME
              FROM   sys.indexes
              WHERE  object_id = (SELECT object_id
                                  FROM   sys.objects
                                  WHERE  NAME = 'TableName')
                     AND type_desc = 'SPATIAL')
           + '))'

PRINT @sql

EXEC(@sql)
```

**Note :** Above query considers in your table there is only one `index` with `type_desc = 'SPATIAL'`

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Is there any other way to do this? I have a rather hairy query that is part of a stored procedure and I hate concatenating a bunch of strings with SQL code...